# Подгрузка новых данных на страницу

Tags: ajax, php, json, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Очень нравится эффект появления данных (новостей, комментариев) у контакта. Как сделать такой же эффект?

Может, кто примеры где видел или решение, писать велосипед, который кто-то уже 100% сделал, не очень хочется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BR055PWp-E

http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1708